# CoffeeScript bind multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I need to replicate the following JavaScript code in CoffeeScript:

```
app.add(function(i) {
    this.items[i].doSomething();
}.bind(this, i));
```

I've tried the following CoffeeScript:

```
app.add((i) =>
    @items[i].doSomething()
)
```

But this results in code that binds "this" but doesn't bind "i"... I need to bind "i" as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js2.coffee says this:

```
app.add ((i) ->
  @items[i].doSomething()
  return
).bind(this, i)
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried using js2.coffee on my phone, but it asks to open in desktop browser. That should work.